# Try Google Cloud Function Locally Without Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to set up a local development environment for Google Cloud Functions - specifically, for the Go runtime - without logging into a Google account? I'd like to try it out locally to decide whether I want to use it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Functions framework is what it's called. The documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework

And details on the Go piece is here: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go

The quickstart for Go:

1) Make sure you have Go 1.11+ installed with:

`go version`

The output should be Go 1.11 or higher.

2) Create the necessary directories.

```
mkdir -p hello/cmd
cd hello
```

3) Create a Go module:

`go mod init example.com/hello`

Note: You can use a different module name rather than example.com/hello.

4) Create a function.go file with the following contents:

```
package hello

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

// HelloWorld writes "Hello, World!" to the HTTP response.
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!\n")
}
```

Note that you can use any file name or package name (convention is to make package name same as directory name).

5) Now go to the cmd subdirectory.

`cd cmd`

6) Create a main.go file with the following contents:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/funcframework"
    "example.com/hello"
)

func main() {
    funcframework.RegisterHTTPFunction("/", hello.HelloWorld)
    // Use PORT environment variable, or default to 8080.
    port := "8080"
    if envPort := os.Getenv("PORT"); envPort != "" {
        port = envPort
    }

    if err := funcframework.Start(port); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("funcframework.Start: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

7) Start the local development server:

```
go build
./cmd
Serving function...
```

8) Send requests to this function using curl from another terminal window:

```
curl localhost:8080
# Output: Hello, World!
```